# Intent between Cordova app to native android applications without plugin

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

I have an old hybrid app, Cordova based and a new, related, native app.
I'm trying to call by href in the web view to open the new app.

by referring to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html i did as follows

in the new app I'v added intent-filter at the manifest, MainActivity section

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="abc6"/>
<data android:host="xyz"/>
```

on the html file (in the old app using Cordova) I'v add href tag pointing at my new app, like so...

```
<a "href="abc6://xyz">push me</a>
```

cant find the reason why it doesn't work.

additional info

1) i don't have block domain on Cordova whitelist

2) when i change the scheme to "http" or "https" it works but open browser options as well

3) i found another approach formatted like:

```
href="intent://xyz#Intent;scheme=<my package name>;package=<my package name>;end"
```

didn't work as well **but it does work when i'm running on browser**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but perhaps a cordova plugin would help? This one seems pretty popular:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme

Comment: I'm trying to avoid native changes so i won't have to uploading a new version to the store. looking for html solution.

Comment: Won't you have to upload a change to the hybrid app regardless (whether it's a plugin or html only solution)?

Comment: Unless of course it is content that is downloaded in the app from a server, then I understand how you're doing that.

Comment: the html content of the app is dynamically downloaded form the app server